# Discrete Mathematics - Show that a conditional statement is a tautology.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am trying to show that the conditional statement:

$$[\mathord{\sim}p \land(p\lor q)] \to q$$

is a tautology without using truth tables. Could someone help me understand how to do this?

Comment: Natural deduction is OK?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I'm guessing. I was only told to use DeMorgan's law.

Comment: And the definition of $\to$, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributing:
$$[(\neg p\wedge p)\vee (\neg p\wedge q)]\implies q$$
$$[c\vee (\neg p\wedge q)]\implies q$$
$$(\neg p\wedge q)\implies q$$

Now, we can convert the implication to disjunction/negation:
$$\neg (\neg p\wedge q)\vee q$$

Using DeMorgan's:
$$(p\vee \neg q)\vee q$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution: consider the law $\sim(p_0\lor q_0)\iff(\sim p_0)\land(\sim q_0)$ (2nd De Morgan Law).

Take $p_0=p$ and $\sim q_0= p\lor q$, then $(\sim p)\land(p\lor q)\implies \sim\{p\lor[\sim(p\lor q)]\}\implies\sim\{p\lor[(\sim p)\lor(\sim q)]\}\implies\ \sim\{[p\lor(\sim p)]\lor(\sim q) \} \implies \sim(\sim q) \implies q.$